# Vim and Emacs users, how to debug as effectively as Eclipse/Netbeans?

Tags: vim, emacs, xdebug

After reading books like The Pragmatic Programmer, one thing it strongly suggested was to pick a text editor and master it. I chose to use Emacs and stuck with it for about half a year.  However, the one thing that kept pulling me back to a full-fledged IDE was debugging.

After attempting to use xdebug via command-line for a couple of weeks, it was no surprise that the debugging tools that Netbeans/Eclipse provide are far superior to CLI.

So fellas, are there any Linux tools that allow you to place breakpoints and help visualize your application at run-time, or is there a reason why I should stick to suffering through CLI debugging?

Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using Vim all day for coding. But when it comes to debugging, I always take the debugger of my IDE (Visual Studio) because while debugging, I take the mouse and hoover over some variables, edit their values and so on. That's not a task that I'd need a powerful editor for.

That's my advice to you: for coding and editing, take an editor; for debugging take a (graphical) debugger ([DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [whatever](http://www.kdbg.org/)). It's not a sacrilege to switch tools, only to take the **wrong** tools for the task to be done.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:  http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/GDB-Graphical-Interface.html#GDB-Graphical-Interface ?
Tutorial :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHOzMOzzxDA

Answer (score 2):

Same.  I use IDEs for the heavy stuff and Emacs for quick stuff.

The reason to be proficient with a light-weight editor is to be nimble when you know what you want to do.  Open this file, find-tag, edit, magit-status, commit, push.  Bam.  You don't want startup-time & instability to be cock-blocking your effort when you've got at goal.  Vim is installed on most servers, and if you're editing on production, you'd *better* have a goal.

IDEs on the other hand (Aptana for me, PHP) I find are useful for "studying".  Debugging, stepping through code, analyzing code, searching (Eclipse's tree-results search over Emac's rgrep ANY day when there are multiple results).

I consider myself quite proficient with using Emacs as a full-fledged IDE via ECB, geben, rgrep, ctags, magit, etc.  I used it as such exclusively for over a year -- but in all honesty, it hindered my productivity -- the heavy tasks take too many steps.  Now I use Aptana & Emacs really about 50/50 throughout the day.

Light editors for light stuff, Heavy editors for the heavy stuff

Answer (score 1):

there are definitely debugging solutions in vim see http://jaredforsyth.com/projects/vim-debug/, there are more but I haven't tried them, I tend to switch back and forth from an ide to vim.